# Small websites - openID instead of SSL?

Tags: security, ssl

I'll be using a shared Internet connexion starting this September at my school and I was wondering about what someone sniffing traffic with Wireshark may find there. I am not planing to do this myself but I feel I ought to know more about it if I want to sometimes work on my website during class.

Basically, isn't every non-SSL website that asks you for a password and an e-mail totally unsecure to log on on a shared connexion? When you know how many people use the same password for all their web/laptop/mobile accounts, it doesn't take long to get access to someone's all private data if you manage to sniff one password and e-mail.

As for me, I am already looking at how to secure my FTP connexions, but what about my users who log through HTTP? Unless I buy a SSL certificate (which I don't want, the site's too small), they are going to get more exposed to Wireshark sniffers all over the world, right? Isn't this where login tools such as OpenID become handy for small communities, since they do provide a free encryption of passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenID and SSL are completely unrelated. OpenID's purpose is to consolidate and give ownership of a user's identity to the user, while SSL is used to keep a user's traffic with your site secret (encrypted). You can use OpenId to keep track of the user (like Stackoverflow does) and still not use SSL for the content pages.

Comment: I know they're not similar technologies, but they are the two (only?) alternatives a webmaster has to protect his users' passwords, aren't they?

Comment: There are other options but yes, if you use OpenID (as a 3rd party) you're basically giving that responsibility to someone else.

Comment: You seem to mean that OpenID is not really secured, is this true? Also, what would these other options you mention be?

Comment: Too many to list :) Depends on your use case. There's everything from Kerberos, X509, public/private keys, even Facebook and Twitter variants. OpenID is just as secure as its implementation. I'm not saying it's insecure at all. I'm just saying that even if you know who the user is you still may want to encrypt the traffic between you two, especially if sensitive information is involved.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I don't think encryption would still be necessary with OpenID in my case, the data is not very sensitive. But I am definitely going to be aware of this in further projects.